# Updating members of a global struct

Tags: c, struct, global-variables

Im trying to update a global linked list with a new node.  I made the list a pointer to a struct and each time I try to assign a new member value to it I get a bus error 10.  Im pretty hung up on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code:

```
typedef struct alarmItem
{
    pthread_t id;  //id of the thread to block/unblock
    int delay;  //initial delay time set by user for this alarm item
    int realdelay;  //adjusted delay time for this item in the queue
    char function[256];  //function for this item to execute once alarm goes off
    char args[256];  //arguments to pass into function, sql query or null
    time_t calltime;  //stores the time that this alarm item was introduced
    struct alarmItem* next;  //stores the next node in the linked list of alarm    items
} alarmItem ;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    alarmItem* head;
} LinkedList;

LinkedList *alarmq;  //empty linkedlist of alarm items

void initList()
{
    if(alarmq == NULL)
        printf("List is null.\n\n");
    else
        alarmq->head = NULL;
}

void entry_point(char **arguments)
{
    char **args = (char **)arguments;

    //create a new alarm item
    alarmItem *new;

    int d;
    sscanf(args[0], "%d", &d);
    new->delay = d;

    strcpy(new->args, args[3]);
    strcpy(new->function, args[4]);

    initList();
}
```

The entry_point function is just being called from the main method with a standard list of string commands.

Comment: this makes absolutely no sense `char **args = (char **)arguments;`.

Comment: `alarmItem *new;` you're not allocating memory for your variable, use malloc for example, also - it is better to avoid reserved c++ words like new even in pure c

Comment: @Lashane If the OP is not using c++ there is no reason to say that. And in fact, it would prevent erroneously compiling with a c++ compiler.

Comment: @iharob the reason im using such a weird data type is because this will eventually be implemented with pthread, which only takes a void data type as an argument, so I left the casting in

Comment: You never allocate space for `alarmq` to point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the `new` struct, for that you need `malloc()`

```
void *entry_point(void *data)
{
    alarmItem *new;
    char **args;
    int d;

    args = (char **)data;
    //create a new alarm item
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    if (new == NULL)
        return NULL; /* may be return something else for error handling */
    sscanf(args[0], "%d", &d);
    new->delay = d;

    strcpy(new->args, args[3]);
    strcpy(new->function, args[4]);

    initList();
    return NULL;
}
```

you can see that I made your `entry_point()` function valid to use with `pthread_create()`.

The same goes for `alarmq`, in fact this condition

```
if (alarmq == NULL)
```

remains true through the lifetime of the program, I don't understand what the `initList()` function is supposed to do, but I guess it would be something like

```
void initList()
{
    if (alarmq == NULL)
    {
        alarmq = malloc(sizeof(*alarmq));
        if (alarmq != NULL)
            alarmq->head = NULL;
    }
}
```

also your linked list `LinkedList` structure is not really a linked list, you need to have the `next` member in it instead of having it in `alarmItem` structure.

Comment: Thanks man, I didnt even think of that.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
to start, replace this:

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    alarmItem* head;
} LinkedList;

LinkedList *alarmq;  //empty linkedlist of alarm items

void initList()
{
    if(alarmq == NULL)
        printf("List is null.\n\n");
    else
        alarmq->head = NULL;
}
```

with this:

```
alarmItem *head = NULL;
```

which greatly simplifies the process, 
eliminates a significant clutter from the code,
and is easy to test if the node to be added is the first
(first node is almost always a special case)
via:

```
if( NULL == head )
{ // then, adding first node 
    ...
}
else
{ // else, all other node additions
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is (I'm assuming) how the first node is being added

however, it has several problems.

-- the current code:

```
void entry_point(char **arguments)
{
    char **args = (char **)arguments;

    //create a new alarm item
    alarmItem *new;

    int d;
    sscanf(args[0], "%d", &d);
    new->delay = d;

    strcpy(new->args, args[3]);
    strcpy(new->function, args[4]);
    initList();
}
```

Which should look more like this:

(this can add any node, including the first.)

```
void entry_point(char **args)
{
    alarmItem *newNode = NULL;
    if( NULL == (newNode = malloc( sizeof(alarmItem) )) )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for alarmItem node failed" );
        cleanup();  // new function to free all allocations
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // amongst other things, this sets newNode->next to NULL
    memset( newNode, 0x00, sizeof(alarmItem) );

    newNode->delay = atoi(args[0]);

    strcpy(newNode->args, args[3]);
    strcpy(newnode->function, args[4]);

    if( NULL == Head )
    { // then, first node to be added
         Head = newNode;
    }

    else
    { // else, append node to end of linked list
        alarmItem *tempNode = Head;
        alarmItem *currentNode = Head;
        while( tempNode->next ) 
        {
            currentNode = tempNode;
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        } // end while

        // when get here, currentNode points to last node in linked list
        currentNode->next = newNode; 
    } // end if    
} // end function: entry_point
```